How to write firmware in vivado?
I’m a logic designer and never written firmware before. On top of that, I have been assigned with task to develop firmware in vivado. I did spend some time learning tool but it’s seems like a nightmare to write firmware or create block diagram.
So, I have ZCU102 FPGA connected to FMC connected to level shifter connected to ASIC. ASIC contains shift register. Now from vivado, I need to develop a firmware which will read data from software and drive FPGA pins and in return read data from FPGA pins and send it back to firmware.
I am confused as do I have to write verilog code and xdc file or create a block diagram. SW uses AXI interface. I’m desperately looking for help with overall algorithm to design firmware.
I created verilog code and connected those signals to FPGA pins via xdc file.
I have,
module shift_register (

input clk,
input reset,
input data_in,
input data_out
);

reg [2333:0] shift_register;

// based on data_in shift value to right at positive edge of clk which is 1MHz

// after 2334 cycles return data_out

Wrote testbench for it and simulated, created bitstream.
I was under impression that SW will be able to drive data_in, but someone in my team said that instead of input these signals need to be output.
I’m totally confused what’s right way to develop firmware for this? If you can give overall algorithm or pseudo code will be helpful. Also not sure where to consider AXI interface? How would petalinux communicate?

I've been through many tutorials, nothing tells precisely what's the flow in such cases

Out of interest, what do you mean by "logic designer"? Do you create electronic schematics? "Firmware" is a software binary that is blown into a read-only memory device. By "firmware", do you actually mean "Verilog"?

Follwoing you need to make.

Make a logical code in vhdl/verilog in Vivado.
Make an AXI interface for it (or AXI Lite) and define some read/write registers in it which are connected to your vhdl/verilog businness logic in Vivado.
In Vivado block design, use it as an AXI IP block and connect it to an AXI interconnect to able to reach it from PS of ZynqMP.
Make an XSA export from Vivado.
Use them from SW

Open XSA in Vitis and you can develop any simple and easy bare-metal SW in C code for reading/writing these AXI register in your IP.
Build a full Linux OS for ZynqMP and read/write your AXI registers via Linux UIO drivers from any language like Python, bash, perl, C/C++ so on ...




Pls presicer what does that mean of firmware here?
An FPGA SoC, or Field-Programmable Gate Array System on Chip, combines the flexibility of an FPGA with the functionality of a traditional SoC. FPGAs are semiconductor devices that can be programmed and reconfigured after manufacturing, allowing for custom logic designs and implementations(PL).
In an FPGA SoC, alongside the FPGA fabric(PL), there is typically a processing system (PS)that includes one or more CPU cores, memory controllers, input/output interfaces, and other peripherals. This integration enables the FPGA to handle both general-purpose processing tasks and customizable hardware acceleration, making FPGA SoCs well-suited for applications requiring a balance between programmability and hardware acceleration, such as signal processing, image processing, networking, and many others.
Arcording your question, you can not write the firmware (if I understand correctly) on Vivado. Instead of that, you can generate the bit stream of your design in PL, then export to Vitis SDK or Xilinx SDK, and write your C code here (firmware). The XDC file is the constraint file which is defined in Vivado to know which pins of FPGA you use for your design.
Best,
